# How to correctly display a single datagridrow within a popup object with the data from a datagrid in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

My overall goal is to create a drag-and-drop functionality within a `datagrid`, so the user can move rows of the datagrid. [To do this, I mainly used this guide from Philip Sumi.](http://www.hardcodet.net/2009/03/moving-data-grid-rows-using-drag-and-drop)
This works fine so far, however I wanted to display the moving datagrid row in a popup with reduced opacity while dragging it:

```
<!-- the popup that is displayed if user moves rows -->
<Popup x:Name="popup1" IsHitTestVisible="False" Placement="Relative" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=me}" AllowsTransparency="True" PopupAnimation="Fade">
    <Border Background="White" Opacity="75" Height="35" BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="0, 1">
        <DataGridRow Name="PopupDataGridRow"/>
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

In the MouseMove event listener I have the following (`row` is the index of the moved `datagridrow`):

```
    if (!popup1.IsOpen)
    {
        PopupDataGridRow = (DataGridRow)m_DataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(row);
        popup1.IsOpen = true;
    }
```

Displaying the popup, placemante relative to mouse, getting the correct row...all of this is working fine. 
Also `PopupDataGridRow` is holding the correct information/data from the respective grid row. However, it is not displayed on the GUI. I only see an empty border.

Is it not possible to display a single datagrid row? I also tried to create an empty `datagrid` within my popup and just add the `datagridrow` to it's items, howeve this results in an exception as soon as the popup is opened:

> {"Specified argument was out of the range of valid
>   values.\r\nParameter name: index"}

How can I correctly display on `datagridrow` within a popup?

Edit: In the meanwhile I'm using a label with a string containing all the `datagridrow`s information.